# nrf52840 not achieving sending 2 Mbps

Tags: nrf-connect, nrf52840

I am developing an accelerometer, which will send the data via Bluetooth to a tablet. I am using the nrf52840 and to program it I am using de nrfConnect SDK. I am sending an 80 position buffer each position of the buffer has 3 int8 inside. The data (with my configurations) is being sent 10 times per second. If my calculations are right: 10 * 80 * 3 = 2400 bytes per second, that is only .0192 Mbps.

I am updating the connection parameters (PHY, data_length, and MTU) when a connection happens, and the parameteres are being updated successfully. I also tried increasing the buffer size, yet I can not increase the size of the buffer, because if I set it to 83, it starts sending more data than capable. Maybe the way i am sending the data is not optimal.

I would appreciate any help!

I will leave some parts of the code here:

```
void send_data_thread(void)
{
    while(1){
        /* Simulate data */
        simulate_data();
        pack_data(sensor_valueX,sensor_valueY,sensor_valueZ);
    }
        
}

static void simulate_data(void){
    simulate_dataX();
    simulate_dataY();
    simulate_dataZ();
}

static void pack_data(uint8_t x, uint8_t y, uint8_t z){
    buffer[buffer_index].x = x;
    buffer[buffer_index].y = y;
    buffer[buffer_index].z = z;
    buffer_index++;

    if (buffer_index == BUFFER_SIZE){
        int err = my_lbs_send_sensor_notify();
        size_t size_of_struct = sizeof(buffer);
        LOG_INF("Size of buffer: %u bytes", size_of_struct);
        if (err) {
            LOG_ERR("Notification failed:  %d", err);
        }
        buffer_index = 0;
    }

}

int my_lbs_send_sensor_notify(void)
{
    if (!notify_sensor_enabled) {
        return -EACCES;
    }

    return bt_gatt_notify(NULL, &accelerometer_svc.attrs[1], 
                  &buffer,
                  sizeof(buffer));
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

UPDATE:
I modified the thread, and now I am able to get .9 Mbps. The modification looks like this:

```
void send_data_thread(void)
{
    while(1){
        if(notify_sensor_enabled){
            simulate_data();
            pack_data(sensor_valueX,sensor_valueY,sensor_valueZ);
        }

    }
        
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to say 2 **K**bps in your title?

Comment: Hi, no, I meant 2 Mbps. I want to achieve the 2 Mbps, but I am getting way below that.

Comment: How far below? 2 Mbps requires Bluetooth 5, and range will make a difference. https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Wireless/Bluetooth-Low-Energy/bluetooth-5

Comment: I am getting approx 2400 bytes per second. That is only  .0192 Mbps. I am using Bluetooth 5 to my knowledge. And about range, right now I am literally doing it 5 cm away.